# String appending operator in Java

Tags: android, string, android-arrayadapter, tostring

Recently I was working on an application to show some file information in an Array Adapter.

So my code looks like this :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTitle("Details");
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         DriveActivity.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
// Case 1
String DIR_NAME = "Directory Name : " + 
         (itemSelectedFile.getTitle() != null ? itemSelectedFile.getTitle() : "");

arrayAdapter.add(DIR_NAME);
// Case 3
arrayAdapter.add(("Directory Md5 Checksum : " + 
                  (itemSelectedFile.getMd5Checksum() != null ?
                       itemSelectedFile.getMd5Checksum(): "").toString()));

// Case 2
arrayAdapter.add("Directory Mime Type : " + 
                 itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() != null ?
                     itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() : "");
```

As you can see I am adding items into ArrayAdapter by three ways :

1. By making a string out of the segment Strings.
2. By Directly adding two Strings in the parametrized add() method of ArrayAdapter without using toString() method on the two segments.
3. By Directly adding two Strings in the parametrized add() method of ArrayAdapter using toString() method on the two segments.

I am getting different results in Case 1 & 3 and 2

In case of both 1 and 3, I am getting the expected results as

1. Directory Name : Cat
2. Directory Md5 Checksum : 'check_sum'

But in the case 2, I am getting this : "mime/type" ( **without the appending** "Directory Mime Type : " !!!)
and in some cases when mimetype is null, I am getting a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.
Anyone please explain me whats happening here.

Comment: you need to check if toString method is overridden for itemSelectedFile.getMd5Checksum() object....

Comment: Good idea, i will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a little mistake. You forget "()":

```
arrayAdapter.add("Directory Mime Type : " + 
             (itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() != null ?
                 itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() : ""));
```

You have these in case 2, but havn't in case 3. That's why your code equals to these:

```
arrayAdapter.add(("Directory Mime Type : " + 
             itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() != null) ?
                 itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() : "");
```

Null pointer exception you have, because your itemSelectedFile = null, i guess. You must to check it, before call getMimeType().

Comment: hmm yeah that was right, actually i oversaw the fact that string concatenation has higher priority than processing of tertiary operator.

Answer (score 2):

It is an operator precedence issue in this expression

```
        "Directory Mime Type : " + 
             itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() != null ?
                 itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() : ""
```

The precedence of the ternary operator (`?`) is lower than both `+` and `!=`.

So that means that the expression actually means the same as this:

```
        (("Directory Mime Type : " + 
             itemSelectedFile.getMimeType()) != null) ?
                 itemSelectedFile.getMimeType() : ""
```